# Why is chrome on my windows machine limiting the number of frequencybins in my script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api

So I am designing a audio visualizer specifically for chrome using web audio and p5.js. Now I know that my code is working fine because it performs as expected on my macbook in chrome as well as on my friend's windows laptop.

I noticed the problem when I was working on a spectrum visualizer. The visualizer uses a for loop to work through each bin (2048/2 = 1024) and output a line corresponding to the frequency data. Now, on my macbook, friends pc, etc, the visualizer shows readout for upwards of 800 bins, as for the other 224 im assuming they just aren't present.

However... on my windows desktop specifically (windows 8.1), I am only getting a max of ~200 bins with output. If I lower the FFT, thus reducing the number of bins, the number that have output are proportionally less in the same way as before.

So... what is up with my desktop that is causing it to process this differently than ever other computer I've tried it on?

Comment: Can you provide code that will demonstrate the issue?

Comment: If you are sure it is your desktop computer then there are two major culprints: the limitation in the OS itself or in the sound card driver.

Answer (score 1):

Or, also quite likely, you have echo cancellation or other pre-processing going on.  Try disabling it with the echoCancellation:false constraint - a la this bit of code (https://github.com/cwilso/Audio-Input-Effects/blob/master/js/effects.js#L52-L57), and passing it to getUserMedia (https://github.com/cwilso/Audio-Input-Effects/blob/master/js/effects.js#L160).